# How to verify checksum without setting its value to zero

Tags: c, networking, network-programming

I have a packet and a checksum function. Before sending out the packet, the checksum field is 0. I calculate the checksum and add the value to the checksum field. At the receiving end, when I use the same checksum function, I get a mismatch because when calculating at the sender end, checksum is initially 0, but at the receiver end the checksum is a different, non zero value.

Work around for this is at the receiver end, make the checksum field equal to 0 and calcuate the checksum but this is not very elegant.

I have been looking for a solution for this but of no avail. The checksum function is pretty standard one and its a black box to me.

How should I fix this?

Comment: This depends entirely on the kind of checksum algorithm you are using. Different kinds of CRC use different initial values. Thus nobody can answer the question unless you tell us what checksum algorithm that is used.

Comment: I'd like to move on but my manager is not allowing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not include the checksum digits in the checksum calculation.  Calculate the checksum on all bytes *excluding* the checksum bytes.

By including the bytes reserved to hold the checksum in the checksum calculation, you are burning a few extra CPU cycles and gaining nothing at all.

Comment: You are making a lot of assumptions on what checksum algorithm that is used. The OP didn't even mention CRC, there are plenty of other kinds of checksums.

Comment: @Lundin No he isn't. I can't see anything in there that depends on the algorithm. The answer is correct for all checksums.